# eBay API Platform Notifications - I'm not receiving all the ones I want

Tags: php, ebay-api

I'm using the eBay API and am trying to receive the following notifications:

- ItemSold
- FixedPriceTransaction
- EndOfAuction

However, the only notification I receive is 'FixedPriceTransaction'.

The code I'm using to 'set' what notifications I receive, looks like this:

```
    $opts = array(
        'ApplicationDeliveryPreferences' => array(
            'ApplicationEnable'  => 'Enable',
            'ApplicationURL'     => 'http://my.domain/ebay_notifications.php',
        ),
        'UserDeliveryPreferenceArray' => array(
            'NotificationEnable' => array(
                'EventType'   => 'ItemSold',
                'EventEnable' => 'Enable'
            ),
            'NotificationEnable' => array(
                'EventType'   => 'EndOfAuction',
                'EventEnable' => 'Enable'
            ),
            'NotificationEnable' => array(
                'EventType'   => 'FixedPriceTransaction',
                'EventEnable' => 'Enable'
            )      
        )
    );
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you send the whole code you used to subscribe to ebay events? Their API is such a mess it could save me hundread of hours. My infos are on my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schoolboy error on my account.

The 'UserDeliveryPreferanceArray' array contains multiple arrays.

All of them have the same key title: 'NotificationEnable'

This means only the last one is used - the one containing the 'FixedPriceNotification' event.

To remedy this, make each 'notification event' part of an indexed array:

```
'NotificationEnable' => array(

                1   =>  array(
                    'EventType'   => 'ItemSold',
                    'EventEnable' => 'Enable' 
                ),

                2   =>  array(
                    'EventType'   => 'EndOfAuction',
                    'EventEnable' => 'Enable' 
                ),

                3   =>  array(
                    'EventType'   => 'FixedPriceTransaction',
                    'EventEnable' => 'Enable' 
                )
            )
```

Happy days.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe i am wrong but the working code should be:

```
$opts = array(
    'ApplicationDeliveryPreferences' => array(
        'ApplicationEnable'  => 'Enable',
        'ApplicationURL'     => 'http://my.domain/ebay_notifications.php',
    ),
    
        'NotificationEnable' => array(

            1   =>  array(
                'EventType'   => 'ItemSold',
                'EventEnable' => 'Enable' 
            ),

            2   =>  array(
                'EventType'   => 'AskSellerQuestion',
                'EventEnable' => 'Enable' 
            ),

            3   =>  array(
                'EventType'   => 'FixedPriceTransaction',
                'EventEnable' => 'Enable' 
            )
            
    )
);
```

And not as I thought:

```
$opts = array(
    'ApplicationDeliveryPreferences' => array(
        'ApplicationEnable'  => 'Enable',
        'ApplicationURL'     => 'http://my.domain/ebay_notifications.php',
    ),
    'UserDeliveryPreferenceArray' => array(
        'NotificationEnable' => array(

            1   =>  array(
                'EventType'   => 'ItemSold',
                'EventEnable' => 'Enable' 
            ),

            2   =>  array(
                'EventType'   => 'EndOfAuction',
                'EventEnable' => 'Enable' 
            ),

            3   =>  array(
                'EventType'   => 'FixedPriceTransaction',
                'EventEnable' => 'Enable' 
            )
        )
);
```

The first one seems to work well so far. The last one generates 37 errors.
Thank you anyways for your huge suggestion.